# How the Revit MEP Connector properties can be exported to IFC entity?

Tags: revit-api, ifc

I found that there is a notion of 'connector' in Revit MEP for piping and ducting.
However, I want to know how the connector properties are exported to IFC format.
Are they exported to ifc elements such as IfcDistributionPort, IfcRelConnectsPortToElement, IfcRelConnectsPort, etc?
Additionally, do I need to change the ifc export setting to export the connector information, or automatically exported?